# Was Agag's mother alive during Saul's time?

Tags: 1-samuel, saul

> "And Samuel said, As thy sword hath made women childless, so shall thy mother be childless among women. And Samuel hewed Agag in pieces before the Lord in Gilgal."- 1 Samuel 15:33.

Was Agag's mother alive when Samuel said this or not? Or was she one of the many people who were killed by "the edge of the sword" a couple of verses earlier? Did the king as an individual usually represent his immediate family?

Or is it something more symbolic? Like condemning Agag and his spawn to a fate of nothingness, where upon death, no-one would be able to revive any trace of their legacies or even any of their memories? The Amalekites seemed to be quite a fierce yet deeply enigmatic enemy for the Israelites.

Comment: We are not told - your mother will be childless is an idiom for being killed.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible gives no information about Agag's mother's status.  However, here is an example where Jeremiah wrote about Rachel, who was obviously dead at the time, as if she were alive:

> This is what the LORD says:

```
A voice was heard in Ramah, 
a lament with bitter weeping— 
Rachel weeping for her children, 
refusing to be comforted for her children 
because they are no more.
```

The Holy Bible: Holman Christian standard version. (2009). (Jer 31:15). Nashville: Holman Bible Publishers.

Mathew quoted this verse related to Herod's slaughter of children in Bethlehem.  This passage also relates to children killed.